# Speed up the search in a PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.4

How to speed up the search in a PostgreSQL database? There are three tables: table_a, table_b, table_c.  Problem that table_a has `450 000` records, table_b has `8 300 000` records, table_c has `1 180 000`
records. 
This query has to wait for about 15 minutes:

```
    select  table_c.* from table_c
left join table_b on table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id
left join table_a on table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
where table_a.id = 1
```

The number of rows may not exceed 500. When I set a limit of up to 500, the query time becomes within 1 second.

Create info:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  latitude numeric(10,8) NOT NULL,
  longitude numeric(11,8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

CREATE TABLE table_b
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  table_a_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT table_b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT table_b_table_a_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (table_a_id)
      REFERENCES table_a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE table_c
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  table_b_id integer,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
  CONSTRAINT table_c_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT table_c_table_b_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (table_b_id)
      REFERENCES table_b (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Additional info:

- OS Windows 7
- Memory 4 gb
- CPU 2 - 3Ghz
- Postgres 9.4.26  64-bit

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well. Ideally turn on `track_io_timing` before doing that (requires superuser access)

Comment: You might want to consider an upgrade to a supported and maintained version of Postgres. 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and there were also substantial performance improvements since 2016. In general a computer with just 4GB is not really suited to work as a database server (most probably with a slow harddisk as well).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. There was missing indexex. Created indexes fix all problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `left join`s are not needed because the `where` clause turns them into inner joins anyway.  So rewrite the query as:

```
select  c.*
from table_c c join
     table_b b
     on b.id = c.table_b_id join
     table_a a
     on a.id = b.table_a_id
where a.id = 1;
```

Then the following indexes should help:  `table_a(id)`, `table_b(table_a_id, id)`, and `table_c(table_b.b_id)`.

Actually, the query can be simplified, because the `table_a` id is in `table_b`:

```
select  c.*
from table_c c join
     table_b b
     on b.id = c.table_b_id 
where b.table_a_id = 1;
```

The first index is not needed for this query.

Finally, if this query might return duplicates and you do not want them, then you might consider:

```
select c.*
from table_c c
where exists (select 1
              from table_b b
              where b.id = c.table_b_id and b.table_a_id = 1
             );
```